# Sante Fe: what kind of cylinder does the clutch have

Tags: clutch, hyundai, 4wd, santa-fe

How can I determine what type of clutch cylinder is on a Hyundai Santa Fe 2007?

An auto mechanic who was giving me an estimate said if it was an "outer" type cylinder it would be very easy and cheap to repair, but if it was an "inner" cylinder it would be very expensive.

In general how can I find out what type of part is in an old car... is there some online repository of repair manuals or something?

The car is 4 wheel drive. I found some videos on YouTube about the clutch system but couldn't understand them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search on ebay shows both external and internal (to the bell-housing) type slave cylinders.

You will need to look at the vehicle and determine which you have.

I used this search string for ebay:

Santa fe 2007 clutch slave cylinder

And the results show both for 2007...

Comment: @tjb see the edit for the string

Answer (score 1):

I like to search parts on RockAuto—eBay's search algorithm is only as good as the person entering the part's description into eBay.  Searching for a 2007 Hyundai Santa Fe 2.7L V6 (there's also a 3.3 but it appears only automatic) shows only this type of slave (there are several brands but all appear similar):

[image]

Which is an *internal* type of slave.  Basically coaxial to the transmission input shaft, as opposed to external, which requires a clutch fork to leverage the throwout bearing.

Comment: can you comment on the difficulty to repair replace internal vs. external? Is the automechanic mentioned in the question giving me correct info?

Comment: Yes.  I have installed both types (external on Miata, internal on Corvette).  External is WAY easier.  An internal slave needs the transmission to be dropped, because the slave fits along the transmission input shaft, and that is inaccessible without removing the transmission.  (For my Vette the entire drivetrain behind the engine needed to be dropped, because it as a torque tube.)  The external, since it just bolts on outside the engine and trans, is much simpler to replace.  If you have the 2.7L, I'm afraid you're screwed, unless you can do the work yourself.

Comment: I'm screwed....

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that!